# Woocommerce Order Update "woocommerce_api_invalid_customer_id" but I'm not trying to update Customer

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

Seems Simple.  I am trying to update an order via the V2 API in WooCommerce.

Here is the request which is being issued :

```
PUT /wc-api/v2/orders/8054?oauth_consumer_key=ck_notgoingtogiveittoyouinexample&oauth_nonce=same&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1436817942&oauth_signature=same HTTP/1.1
```

Here is the json in the request body :

```
{"order": {"status": "completed"}}
```

Here is the result I am getting :

```
{"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_invalid_customer_id","message":"Customer ID is invalid"}]}
```

The weird thing is, I am not asking to update the customer id, or anything besides the status.

Also, when this happens, WooCommerce does update the status, but it doesn't set it correctly.

I am getting a status note on the order of :

> { Order status changed from to {.

Do I have to serialize the entire order object back to the server?  If not, any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

[UPDATE #1]

So, after tracing through the API code, and adding some debug logging, I noticed the $data is not being set at all coming into the update function from the route.  Since I am following all of the appropriate requirements "json in the request body, with json content type in the header", I am not sure what is going on.  I was able to resolve this by using the API code as a template to create my own order update function.  Now I am simply calling my own FlagOrderCompleted and it's working fine because I am not having to pass parameters.  It's hacky and it isn't a catch all solution but at least it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Customer id is required in the json body in order to successfully update the order. Please refer to this [Resolved issue](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/7666). And also [this](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#view-an-order) link for referring to the syntax of body with customer id.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  I have passed customer_id along with the order status and it didn't make a difference.  I tried serializing the entire object back, still no dice.  After reviewing and modifying the woo commerce api plugin code to log some stuff, I realized the $data value is not being passed at all in from the route.  I am still not sure what I am missing, it is being passed as JSON in the request body, and the content type is set correctly.